# Getting message “Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0)” ?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, primary-key

Another big problem, here.

I have the model:

```
public class Lead
    {
        [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Column("le_codlead")]
        public int LeadID {get; set; }

        [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Column("le_descr1")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage="Inserire Nome del Lead")]
        [Display(Name="Nominativo Lead")]
        public string Name1 {get; set;}

        [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Column("le_descr2")]
        [Display(Name = "Nominativo secondario")]
        public string Name2 { get; set; }
        ...
        ...
        ...
    }
```

Controller (for the Create Method):

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Lead lead)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Leads.Add(lead);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");  
            }
            return View(lead);
        }
```

and this is the View:

```
@model CRMArcadia.Models.Lead

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "ATTENZIONE! Compilare tutti i campi obbligatori")
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Lead</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name1)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name1)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name1)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name2)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name2)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name2)
        </div>
        ...
        ...
        ...
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset> }
```

But when I try to insert a new Lead it throws the exception as in the Post Title: Entity Framework: “Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0).” I read on the web it is caused by the ID key (LeadID, in this case) not updating: they suggest to insert an hiddenfor attribute in the view for the ID key, and so I did:

```
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.LeadID)
```

But with this one at the pressure of the Create button nothing happens.

Does someone has a solution (or a workaround ;) ) at this problem, please?

Thanks.

Comment: are you using code first approach?

Comment: what do you mean nothing happens? do you get into the controller action? are you passing the ModelState.IsValid? are you trying to update this model? or insert a new value?

Comment: what is your EF database context? Something is not set right there, you need to investigate it.

Comment: With "nothing happens" I mean when I click the Create button it does nohing. I put breakpoints in the Create action method and the debug never reach them (I put the HiddenFor before every other editor-lable & editor-field as shown)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have some extra layer to communicate with EF ? what is your entity context?

**For Update scenario:**

If you are using same action for Create/Edit then just place your  `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.LeadID)`  - hidden field between blocks `@using (Html.BeginForm()) {   .... </fieldset> }`.

If it does not help, look at this article [MSDN - Working with Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738470)

Comment: It shouldn't even matter however if his database is set up to seed the primary ID's anyway. He is passing this stuff to a create method. no updating is being done.

Comment: I suppose same action used for Create/Edit. That might be reason why he get error.

Comment: That could be. If it's an update his controller action is completely wrong however.

Comment: Nope, it only happens in Create action method: the Edit action method works (I think that's because in the Edit method I pass the id _public ActionResult Edit(int id)_)

Comment: More infos: I looked for the source code generated for the hiddenfor and this is what I get: <input data-val="true" data-val-number="Il campo LeadID deve essere un numero." data-val-required="Il campo LeadID &amp;#232; obbligatorio." id="LeadID" name="LeadID" type="hidden" value="" />. Value shouldn't be "", right?

Comment: No Value should be the value of the LeadID. Your lead id must not be populating properly